# Swapping user integer input for a variable so that it incrementally increases and decreases

Tags: java

As the title says, I'm trying to replace the "i" variable listed with what a user inputs so that it'll incrementally increase and decrease based off of whatever they put in for the base integer when prompted. Basically I want my "for" loops to base the increment off of whatever the speed integer entered is.

I've tried inputting various things but clearly I don't know what I'm doing or clearly what those particular are. Also I have no idea what the standards are for writing Java so I apologize for the sloppy code.

Here is my actual objective:

> #### 2. Car Class
>
> Write a class named car that has the following fields:
>
> - yearModal. The yearModel field is an int that holds the car's year model.
> - maka. The make field references a String object that holds the make of the car.
> - speed. The speed field is an int that holds the car's current speed.
>
> In addition, the class should have the following constructor and other methods.
>
> - Constructor. The constructor should accept the car's year model and make as arguments. These values should be assigned to the object's yearModel and make fields. The constructor should also assign 0 to the speed field.
> - Accessor. Appropriate accessor methods should get the values stored in an object's yearModel, make, and speed fields.
> - accelerate. The accelerate method should add 5 to the speed field each time it is called.
> - brake. The brake method should subtract 5 from the speed field each time it is called.
>
> Demonstrate the class in a program that creates a Car object, and then calls the accelerate method five times. After each call to the accelerate method, get the current speed of the car and display it. Then call the brake method five times. After each call to the brake method, get the current speed of the car and display it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarProgramAssignment {
    int yearModel;
    String make;
    int speed;

    CarProgramAssignment(int yearModel, String make) {
        this.yearModel = yearModel;
        this.make = make;
        this.speed = 0;
    }

    int getYearModel()
    {
      return yearModel;
    }

    String getMake() {
      return make;
    } 

    int getSpeed() {
      return speed;
    }

    void Accelerate() {
       this.speed = this.speed + 5;
    }

    void Brake() {
    this.speed = this.speed - 5;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args)
    {

     Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

      // This displays the current status
      System.out.println("Current status of the car:");
      System.out.println("Car Year: ");

      int carMakeYear = input.nextInt();

      input.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Car Make: ");
      String carModel = input.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Speed: ");

      int speed = input.nextInt();    

     CarProgramAssignment car = new CarProgramAssignment(1, "Audi R8");
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
     car.Accelerate();
     }

     System.out.printf("After accelerating 5 times, the speed is = %d km/h\n", car.getSpeed());
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        car.Brake();
     }

     System.out.println("After braking 5 times, the speed is = "+car.getSpeed());

    }
}
```

Edit: I cleaned up some things and tried to clarify it a bit more.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you give sample input and output? What does the loop do? Why are the two loop lines the same?

Comment: Do you want to change the number of calls how often the `accellerate()`/`brake()` methods are called or do you want to change the increment/decrement offset one call of `accelerate()`/`brake()` will apply to the speed?

Comment: You might want to remove the loops near the top of your post. They don't do anything an are confusing.

Comment: @ModusTollens This is the input and output. Really the year and make do not matter, however I do want the speed to matter.

Current status of the car:

Car Year: 

 [DrJava Input Box]

Car Make: 

 [DrJava Input Box]

Speed: 

 [DrJava Input Box]

After accelerating 5 times, the speed is = 25 km/h

After braking 5 times, the speed is = 0

Comment: @Progman I want the speed value entered in from the "int speed = input.nextInt(); " section by the user to be the base. Currently it increases at an increment of 5, starting at 0 (which I can't change right now). I want the speed to be the base value, so that if it started at 20, it would increase at an increment of 5 from there and not from 0.

Comment: @mightymorphinParkRanger What is the problem in changing the constructor to allow setting the base speed or adding a new method which sets the speed?

Comment: @Progman I think I kinda understand what you mean. However where I'm confused is how I get that method to change no matter what the user enters. Since the accelerate method increases by 5, 5 times, I want it to adjust accordingly whether the user enters 0, 1, 5, 20, 100. I mean is there a way to call the method where I have "i" now?

Comment: Sort of. You'll need to input a value from the keyboard with your scanner object. Something like: int x = input.nextInt()

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but start with replacing `new CarProgramAssignment(1, "Audi R8")` to `new CarProgramAssignment(carMakeYear,carModel)`. Then add `System.out.println(car.getMake());` before your loops. You'll notice that the use of the variable in the `new CarProgramAssignment(...)` is being used to set the value in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code slightly and added some explanations inside it.

The `nextLine()` will scan a line including the linefeed. If you use `next()`, or `nextInt()` the scanner will not read the linefeed. This seems to be a general source of confusion for beginners.

I changed your constuctor in the `Car` class, so it doesn't halt and wait for the user input. Instead I placed scanning for "speed" input where the other information is scanned as well. I also changed the `Car` to have two constructors. One that will work if there's no speed provided and another that will take a speed as well as the year and model of the car.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Car { // Class names start with uppercase

    private int yearModel; //an int that holds the car's year model
    private String make; //references a string object that holds the make of the car
    private int speed; //an int that holds the car's speed.

    public int getYearModel() {
        return yearModel;
    }

    public String getMake(){ 
        return make; //This is the field of the particular object
    }

    public int getSpeed(){ 
        return speed;
    }

    public void accelerate() {
        speed = speed + 5;
    }

    public void brake() {
        speed = speed - 5;
    }

//    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Avoid IO-dependency in constuctor

    public Car(int yearModelGiven, String makeGiven){
        this.yearModel = yearModelGiven;
        this.make = makeGiven;
        this.speed = 0;
//        System.out.println("Please enter in the initial speed of the car:");
//        speed = input.nextInt();
    }

    // Overloaded constructor
    public Car(int yearModelGiven, String makeGiven, int speed){ // extra parameter
        this.yearModel = yearModelGiven;
        this.make = makeGiven;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

}

public class Application{

    public static void main(String [] args ) { //this is a main method

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );  

        System.out.println("What is the vehicle year: ");
        int carYear; 
        carYear = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine(); // This line will scan the rest of the line after the number: The linefeed.
        System.out.println("The vehicle year is " + carYear);

        System.out.println("What is the vehicle make: ");
        String carMake;
//        carMake = input.nextLine(); // nextLine() scans the rest of the line including the linefeed
// The above line will do the same as the below two:
        carMake = input.next();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The vehicle make is "+ carMake);

        System.out.println("Please enter in the initial speed of the car:");
        int speed = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine(); // This line will scan the rest of the line after the number: The linefeed.

//        Car car1 = new Car(carYear, carMake);  // will give it default speed 0
        Car car1 = new Car(carYear, carMake, speed); // will give it the speed entered by user.

        System.out.println( "Accelerating the vehicle now:" );  
        for( int seconds = 1; seconds <= 5; seconds++ ) {
            car1.accelerate();
            System.out.println( "The current speed of the" + " " + car1.getYearModel() + " " + car1.getMake() + " is " +
                      car1.getSpeed() + " km/h" );
        }

        // This is now the braking method
        System.out.println( "Braking the vehicle now:" );
        for (int seconds = 1; seconds <= 5; seconds++ ) {
             car1.brake();
             System.out.println( "The current speed of the" + " " + car1.getYearModel() + " " + car1.getMake() + " is " +
                      car1.getSpeed() + " km/h" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I actually went to a tutor at my school in the meantime and he showed me those exact same things. Our text and my instructor never went over that for the next() function. This whole time we've been doing nextLine() so that has helped me  a bunch.

Comment: @mightymorphinParkRanger I'm pleased this helped you. You can choose to accept an Answer that best fits your Question, or that you feel is either the best Answer or the one that helped you most. Use the current gray check mark, see the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). There's nothing wrong with marking your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I sort of figured it out. I created 2 classes and started over and this sort of works now.

Here is my first class:

```
public class carclass1 {//Start of Class

    private int yearModel; //an int that holds the car's year model
    private String make; //references a string object that holds the make of the car
    private int speed; //an int that holds the car's speed.

    public int getYearModel() {
        return yearModel;
    }

    public String getMake(){ 
        return make; //This is the field of the particular object
    }

    public int getSpeed(){ 
        return speed;
    }

    public void accelerate() {
        speed = speed + 5;
    }

    public void brake() {
        speed = speed - 5;
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public carclass1( int yearModelGiven, String makeGiven ){
        yearModel = yearModelGiven;
        make = makeGiven;
        System.out.println("Please enter in the initial speed of the car:");
        speed = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

SECOND CLASS:

```
public class carclass2{

    public static void main(String [] args ) { //this is a main method

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );  

        System.out.println("What is the vehicle year: ");

        int carYear; 
        carYear = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println( "The vehicle year is "+ carYear + " (type a number on the` next prompt to proceed");
        carYear = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println( "What is the vehicle make: ");

        input.nextLine(); /*The purpose for this is to skip to the next prompt
        * I couldn't find another way around why my code won't work without it.*/
        String carMake1;
        carMake1 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println( "The vehicle make is "+ carMake1);

        carclass1 car1 = new carclass1( carYear, "Honda" );

        System.out.println( "Accelerating the vehicle now:" );  
        for( int seconds = 1; seconds <= 5; seconds++ ) {
            car1.accelerate();
            System.out.println( "The current speed of the" + " " + car1.getYearModel() + " " + car1.getMake() + " is " +
                      car1.getSpeed() + " km/h" );
        }

        // This is now the braking method
        System.out.println( "Braking the vehicle now:" );
        for (int seconds = 1; seconds <= 5; seconds++ ) {
             car1.brake();
             System.out.println( "The current speed of the" + " " + car1.getYearModel() + " " + car1.getMake() + " is " +
                      car1.getSpeed() + " km/h" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should name the class that represents a car `Car`, and the test program should be a separate class.

Comment: Class names should begin in uppercase so they don't get confused with variable names, which starts in lowercase. Also, the code for reading the base speed shouldn't be added to your new `carclass1` constructor. It is not the job of that class to read user inputs. Do this outside this class and provide the base speed as a new argument for the constructor like `new carclass1(carYear, "Honda", baseSpeed);`, where `baseSpeed` contains the base speed asked before from the user.